# How to connect RestDatasource in Wso2-DAS server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

My RestwebApplication Deploy the Das Server in 
repository\deployment\server\webapps   this Location.

How to MyRestwebApplication Using Connect RestDatasource in Das Dashboard

Any one Pls Answer this Question